# Finding out where would a value "fit" in an Array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, logic

I'm having a trouble with what should be a very simple algorithm, but for some reason my head is not working properly (too much work?)

I have an Array of numeric values:  [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 100, 1000, 5000, 100000]  I want to check which is the next "item" in the array.

For example,

- given the number 10, my algorithm should return 10.
- given the number 1, my algorithm should return 10
- given the number 50, my algorithm should return 100.
- given the number 99999999, my algorithm should return 100000

In pseudo-code I was thinking:

```
for previousValue, nextValue in values: 
  if ( previousValue < value && nextValue >= value ):
    return nextValue
return values[max]
```

If anyone can point out to my exhausted brain what I'm missing it would be great.  thanks!

Comment: Is your array always sorted?

Comment: Even if it's not sorted, one could always sort beforehand and use binary search I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is already sorted, your solution works fine. But to make it more clear I would rewrite it as follows:

```
  prev = 0
  for(v in values){
        if(target > prev && target <= v) 
              return v
        prev = v
  }
  return values[values.length-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In ruby :

```
find 0,values.length,val
def find left,right,val
    if left == right || left > right then return values[left]
    if val > values[(right + left)/2]
        find (right + left)/2, right, val
    else
        find left, (right + left)/2, val
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the array need not be sorted. sorting an array has O(nlogn) time complexity. You can check each element in the array in theta(n) time.

Assuming the array is `arr` and the comparison item is `item` and the array `arr` contains at least one element greater than or equal to `item`:

In java

```
public static int find_greater(int[] arr,int item)
{
    int j=0;
    int previous =0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]>=item){
            if(j==0){
                previous = arr[i];

             }else{
                 if(arr[i]<previous)
                 {
                     previous = arr[i];
                 }
             }
             j++;

        }
    }
    return previous;
}
```

Here I go through the array and keep a variable `previous` which is the smallest number greater or equal `item`.
The running time for this procedure is `theta(N)` where N is `arr.length`.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably represent this array as a tree.
To find out the closest biggest value, I will just look in the tree the same way I will do to find a key, and always keep track of my closest value. When I reach the end of the node, I return the closest value.

This is another alternative, compared to the other answers. You can check it in this thread [How to find the closest element to a given key value in a binary search tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209325/how-to-find-the-closest-element-to-a-given-key-value-in-a-binary-search-tree)